Change Data Type for MYSQL UPDATE for error 1292 Truncated Error Double Value on WHERE failing on VARCHAR(45)
I have looked at all error 1292 Truncated Error Double Value questions, but have not been able to derive a solution from them.
Answers have however led me to an assumtion that I am failing to prove:
I am querying MYSQL out of NODEJS using the MYSQL2 library. My table named shoptableplayground contains a column/field named regular_price. It has the data type attribute VARCHAR(45).
I would like to increase the value of said column/field by 10% for all rows.
I am getting error 1292 from the following query:
UPDATE shoptableplayground 
SET regular_price = regular_price * 1.1 WHERE regular_price BETWEEN 1 AND 200; 

I am assuming that I am getting the error because WHERE expects to compare numerical data types (DEC, INT etc.) in order to be able to do the actual comparison.
My various attempts of incoorporating CONVERT or CAST or even ALTER TABLE MODIFY COLUMN datatype all lead to MYSQL SYNTAX ERRORS. Unfortunately most tutorials cover either SELECT or some form of direct data manipulation.
I've also tried rebuilding the table with a DECIMAL(10.2) column for column regular_price, but the populating process (outside my control) seems to insert the Data as string / VARCHAR nevertheless.
Any query suggestion on how to solve the issue would be much appreciated.

if your table holds strings, convert the string to a number that you can multiply by 1.1 when you do this calculation. Then also convert your result back to a string when you save it. You need to show your attempts with the syntax errors if you would like us to help you fix the syntax errors.

I do now how convert strings in Node JS, but not in MYSQL.

Well, you just google cast and convert, and start there. It seems you in fact have already tried ... so what went wrong?

Show a sample of the values which are stored in the column in question. It seems that your string values are not correct numeric ones (for example, a comma is used as decimal separator).

@topsail it is difficult to document all the 20 - 30 variations I tried. They all led to the same Error or Syntax error.

@Akina TY! As shown (now) in the error message, commented in under your answer, '731,17'. This is in fact the regular_price value of the first row in the table.

In German, comma is used as decimal mark and dot is used to separate thousands.

This question is similar to: Regular expression to match German number. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Unfortunatelely we were only able to solve the issue by providing the data the correct (english formatted, decimals with . not ,) way.
Neither Node JS nor MYSQL Terminals had any problems with the data type of the column being VARCHAR(45) hereafter.
All attempts of trying to replace , vs . within a MYSQL query, or changing the data type of the field failed for reasons beyond my noobish scope.
TYVM for everyone who helped! For time constraiting reasons I have to move on, but will review in some time. TY!

First of all, It's a big mistake to store a calculated number as a VARCHAR type, but we'll ignore it for now.
Focus, you have a column contains many rows filled by prices(floats) but it is considered as a VARCHAR column we cannot do calculations on it.
The Trick is Casting two times :

the 1st time : Casting from VARCHAR to FLOAT to do the desired calculation
the 2nd time : casting the result of the calculation which considered as a FLOAT
Type to The Column Type(VARCHAR)

also you will cast the condition the ensure the interval of the price(between 0 and 200)
UPDATE shoptableplayground
SET regular_price = CAST(CAST(regular_price AS DECIMAL(10,2)) * 1.1 AS CHAR)
WHERE CAST(regular_price AS DECIMAL(10,2)) BETWEEN 1 AND 200;

Edit :
Since you use the comma (,) as a decimal seperator and the MySQL expects periods (.) as decimal seperators, you should replace comma by periods.
UPDATE shoptableplayground
SET regular_price = CAST(CAST(REPLACE(regular_price, ',', '.') AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) * 1.1 AS CHAR)
WHERE CAST(REPLACE(regular_price, ',', '.') AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) BETWEEN 1 AND 200;



Thank you very much. Unfortunately I am still getting the following error:
code: 'ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE',
errno: 1292,
sql: 'UPDATE shoptableplayground SET regular_price = CAST(CAST(regular_price AS DECIMAL(10,2)) * 1.1 AS CHAR) WHERE CAST(regular_price AS DECIMAL(10,2)) BETWEEN 1 AND 200;',
sqlState: '22007',
sqlMessage: "Truncated incorrect DECIMAL value: '731,17'"
Could it have something to do with the data being German and having a comma?

@IoT-Practitioner you can answer your own question by trying 731.17 instead of 731,17

@topsail it is not as easy as it may sound. I would have loved to keep this to purely technical information required to answer my question. Another department exports a huge chunk of shop data to CSV. A library (with near to no configurability) streams the CSV to MYSQL. I did indeed try to change one value to "." , which led to the library taking this as a default and errored the remaining rows. Let's please focus on solving the query or stating that it can not be done.

You can run your query in MySQL directly to test this. Your "library" does not need to prevent you from making such a test. I.e., as simple as select cast('731.17' as decimal(10,2)) compared to select cast('731,17' as decimal(10,2)) This is exactly what we would do to test a proposed answer your question and you can certainly do it yourself. As far as focusing on the solution - well, this is laser focused on that as it is likely the problem.

@topsail seeing your experience I will just blindly follow along :) I have executed both commands. The first one (.) gives me 731.17 end the second one (,) returns 731.00 when running MYSQL in terminal (Linux), but it (, version) throws a parse error 1064, when executed in Node.

you can't keep working with this database and you don't follow the rules.
So first you need to change the column type to be float and following the US/English Notation of numbering and changing the old rows to to comply with the new type.
and to stay out of risk, we will create a new column to hold the successfully converted rows, then we will remove the original row and renaming the new column as if nothing has changed.
apply these queries separately, if one failed don't apply the next until you resolve the first query problem
/* create new column with the suitable type */
ALTER TABLE shoptableplayground
ADD COLUMN new_regular_price DECIMAL(10, 2);

/* filling the new column with the well-formated data */
UPDATE shoptableplayground
SET new_regular_price = CAST(REPLACE(regular_price, ',', '.') AS DECIMAL(10, 2));

/* remove the old column and rename the new column with the old column name*/
ALTER TABLE shoptableplayground
DROP COLUMN regular_price;
ALTER TABLE shoptableplayground
RENAME COLUMN new_regular_price TO regular_price;


OK I'm back at it. TYVM for keeping at it! I got an answer from the web team: They need the field as VARCHAR as otherwise the comma would cause all sorts of errors and the program that streams the CSV data would not write at all. I am trying your solution now

Unfortunately both answers did not work for me. As soon as the web team fed the data in with a "." everything worked like a charm. It is a bit unfortunate, as we do have an extra step now for every price change, but for reasons of time constraint I have to move on unfortunately.
Also thanks to the downvoter. Sorry I was too stupid for you..

@IoT-Practitioner don't be ashamed, at least you are asking and trying to learn, since i have goes deep with you in this problem i will not let you go until you resolve it. just provide me with more details. and don't forget that i edit the first answer, take another look at it.

TY! I did try both your updated answers, but unfortunately the query does not execute in either case, unless I change the data in the CSV befor import. To me as a noob this looks like queries are not compatible with german decimals in such cases. But how can that be? Surely mysql must have accomodated for the possibility of data in other language format?
